# How to timeout firefox kali linux

Tags: command-line, kali-linux, command, firefox, command-history

I want to timeout Firefox on Kali linux with a command. Can you help me? I tried `sleep 10` and `kill firefox 10`.nothing happend after i done this

Comment: Hello Türkeitürkei. What happened when you tried `sleep 10` and `kill firefox 10`? Did they give any errors? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/716644/edit) with these details. _Do not_ reply here in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The programm `timeout` is part of GNU coreutils and does exactly what you need:

```
timeout 10 firefox
```